# How to prevent Google Maps from using Google Gears under Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-maps, geolocation, google-gears

I've just allowed Google Maps to access my current location by enabling Google gears for the same service.

I want to know how do I disable Google Gears now, even for Google Maps or any other website that may ask for enabling Google Gears under chrome.

Under Firefox I can use Tools > page info -> share location = disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=97489:

> 1. Click the wrench menu.
> 2. Select Options.
> 3. Click the Under the Hood tab.
> 4. In the 'Web Content' section, click Change Gears settings.
> 5. The Gears dialog box that opens shows you the list of websites that
>      are allowed to access Gears, as well
>      as the list of websites that you've
>      set to never access Gears. Adjust your
>      settings here, then click Save.
> 6. Click Close.